# "Shortage" or "shortening"?

Tags: nouns

SAD(seasonal affective disorder) is a response to the shortening of daylight hours and lack of sunlight in winter.

The sentence above is extracted from the book that I'm studying by myself right now named Grammar and Vocabulary for Advanced by Martin Hewings and Simon Haines. The answer is **shortening**,however, I cannot understand as I think we can use **shortage** in this case.

Can you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: shortening is a verbal noun. It means 'making short', whereas shortage is a noun that refers to quantity/ volume. Shortening and Shortage are usually not interchangeable.

Comment: 'Daylight hours' here is figurative for 'length of day' ('day' in the 'daylight time' sense). Hence the **shortening** of this length (daily period) as the winter solstice approaches (another figure of speech). If we chose 'shortage', this would mean that we are using 'daylight hours' to mean say the total weekly number of hours of daylight. This is not the default sense here, so the choice of 'shortage' (or 'lack' [of daylight hours]) would be less idiomatic.

Comment: thanks so much Ram Pillai and Edwin Ashworth.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I agree with you. *Shortage* would make more sense, although it would imply something different from what the author meant.

*Shortening* refers to something getting shorter, in this case it is the *day* (as in "the part of the day during which we receive sunlight", opposed to night) that gets shorter.
The daylight *hours*, however, do not get shorter. They are still 60 minutes long.

The *number* of hours during which we receive sunlight, however, decreases, thus causing a *shortage* of such hours.

Purely grammatically, within our current system of defining hours as being of a constant length, I agree that *shortage* makes more sense than *shortening*.

But...

If we read *daylight hours* as a descriptive form of "day" (the light part, as opposed to night), it *does* get shorter, and *shortening of days* makes grammatical sense.

Furthermore, using *shortage* would imply a different situation: if I experience a shortage of daylight hours, I would assume, for some reason, that I'm not getting enough daylight because, for instance, I'm staying inside too much. I would not associate that with the changing of the seasons. *Lengthening* and *shortening* of the days I *do* associate with the changing seasons.

Therefore, I understand the author's choice for *shortening*, even though the *days* get shorter, and not the hours.

On a side note, in ancient Rome, this sentence would have made more sense (provided it were written in Latin...).
In Rome, the day was divided into twelve hours between sunrise and sunset, meaning that an hours did not always have the same length. Under that system, one could indeed observe that in fall, the *hours* would shorten.

Comment: thanks so much oerkelens.

Answer (score 0):

Shortage is a noun and shortening is a verb here.

In this case, shorten refers to the process of the days becoming gradually shorter as winter approaches. Shortage would refer to a quantity being less than a required amount. The shortening of days may very well result in a shortage of sunlight. In fact, the word "lack" can be a synonym for shortage, so they probably chose lack over shortage for style reasons.

Comment: But _shortening_ is not applied to the length of _days_, but to the _daylight hours_. How would you address that? Can an amount become shorter?

Comment: Good point. The use of daylight hours is a bit figurative, but means the same thing. I will edit my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't use it at all, but your idea, although erroneous, makes a lot of sense. Since "shortening" means making shorter then logically shortening causes a lack (of something) and vice versa if there exist a shortening of something then that is translated *possibly* into a deficiency, therefore a shortage. Therefore using one word or the other seems possible as the situation can be characterized by either of two concepts irremediably tied by cause and effect. This apparently correct and nice reasoning, however, does not stand the test of usage.

"Shortage" means strictly, if dictionaries do not specify it explicitly, "deficiency *as it relates to a usual supply in support of a man made or animal made system*". In the present case the daylight has no such recognized function of support. Of course, daylight has an action in a system at large, the system of the biosphere of which man is a part. It is not a man made system. For instance we do say that there is a shortage of ozone; ozone is being rarefied but is not an element of man made system.

As our outlook on our evironment evolves we go on to considering as man made systems new entities  that apparently create contradictions, but only apparently. It wouldn't occur to anyone to speak about a shortage of whatever wild animal we can think about if not in the context of a system conceived by animals; species just become extinct; nevertheless, there is no problem talking about shortages of animals that have a function in a man made system; here is the example of a [shortage of dairy cows](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11250-012-0087-3). Beavers are wild animals and we suspect the principle to be valid for them too; however this is not quite so: beavers are an element of a portion of the ecosystem in which man has lately become an active agent of change and has therefore began to create a man made system. In this context the word "shortage" has began incidentally to be applied to beavers ([ref.](https://www.martinezbeavers.org/wordpress/2017/03/14/there-isnt-a-beaver-shortage-just-a-beaver-dam-shortage/)).

The reason for not being able to use "shortage of daylight" is usage, usage that requires the existence of a man made system (unrecorded usage should I say).

Comment: _Hours_ are definitely a man-made concept, so why couldn't there be a shortage of hours? I don't see why shortage would only apply to man-made or animal systems anyway. Bees can experience a shortage of pollen, land can endure a shortage of rain. Of course, if you fit everything into the biosphere, and man is part of that, so everything goes, it works, but it makes your restriction rather useless.

Comment: I think this is a good attempt to explain the restrictions on the distribution of 'shortage'. (Was that sentence idiomatic?) But I'm not sure it's the complete answer. I've a strong suspicion that the evil term 'idiosyncratic' fits to some extent.

Comment: @oerkelens **1/** In my opinion, you can't use "shortage of hours" because they are not ***part* of a man-made system** in the context of the length of the day. **2/** In fact, a hive does constitute an animal made or rather a creature made system. **3/** It is true that "shortage of rain" is in  common use (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2008&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&content=shortage+of+rain&corpus=15&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshortage%20of%20rain%3B%2Cc0); rain is such an important  factor in the world of agriculture that it almost becomes a part of (1/4)

Comment: @oerkelens  that sytem as it operates for it regularly and powerfully; so, what I do see as an exceptional use, might after all not be so  exceptional because of the close connection with the man made system that is agriculture, the great influence that vital system has on the mind of man explaining the usage. Let's not forget that in almost everything there are exceptions; however, I agree with you, this thesis has not been proven fully and should be researched much more thouroughly. **4/** My point of view is far from being as simple as to fit everything into the biosphere,  (2/4)

Comment: @oerkelens which by the way, is an assertion I do not quite understand; one point concerning that question is that the biosphere is not a man made system but that as time goes by, man can exert more and more control over it, thus creating progressively a more extensive man controlled system, albeit still a *very small subsystem* dependent on  something enormously vast in comparison (the biosphere); on the contrary, connecting something to the biosphere does not justify it; it happens (or so I think) that **a system** (creature made) would justify it, be it narrowly tied to ) (3/4).

Comment: @oerkelens  uncontrollable events in the biosphere (beavers) or not (dairy cows); I do say, on the contrary, that although the variations of the length of the days is a factor in a system, the biosphere, that system is not man made, wherby the unaturalness of the usage. (4/4)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A coincidental collective choice of the users of the language rather than a more or less instinctual dictating to them of a particular area of application would then be the explanation…

Comment: That comment needs shortage.